# Passing dynamically created TextBox object to another method?

Tags: c#

How to pass TextBox object to textBox1_TextChanged method?

```
    public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       //I would like to do something like string value = tb.Text;

    }

//method for creating TextBox on button click, than firing event to save value
//from user input on TextChanged

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox tb = new TextBox();

        this.Controls.Add(tb);
        tb.BringToFront();
        tb.Click += new System.EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
    }
```

I know this is basic, but I am newbie. 
Thank You for your help.

Comment: Check out the `sender` argument, e.g. `var tb = (TextBox)sender;`

Comment: Why are you binding the `click` event to `changed` handler? Other from that, the code you already have should work. What is the issue?

Comment: @IvanStoev thank You!  var tb = (TextBox)sender; string value = tb.Text; MessageBox.Show(value); I am getting empty MessageBox, because change happen on clicking textbox. How to get message with user input, after input is done ?

Comment: @HristoYankov probably my approach isnt good, its my first time practicing WFA. My idea was to create textbox on click to button, and after user input to store value

Comment: Subscribe to `TextChanged` event instead of `Click`? e.g. `tb.TextChanged += ...`

Comment: @IvanStoev maybe even better solution would be tb.Leave += ..., because it will store whole string instead of only first character, do you agree?

Comment: Actually the "standard" place for such things is [`Validating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) event. `Leave` and `LostFocus` are unreliable, the `Validating` event has been specifically provided (it's also the default for data binding).